# How to prevent dos(denial of service) attack?

Tags: denial-of-service, algorithm

Hi is there any solid algorithm or solution where I can refer to for preventing dos (denial of service)attack on my apache server ? I did the dos attack using slowloris in ubuntu and switchblade in windows targeting my local server.

Comment: There are [lots of questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Asecurity.stackexchange.com+prevent+dos+web+server) on this site which cover this kind of topic. In short: it is not a simple task and there is no "solid algorithm". There are a number of solutions, products and services for various kinds of DoS though (slowloris is not the only kind of DoS).

Comment: Denial of Service attacks can't be stopped algorithmically. That's like asking "Is there an algorithm to prevent headaches?"